# get byobu to run custom notification out of current directory ($PWD)

Tags: byobu

any way to get byobu to run custom notification out of current directory ($PWD) of terminal
I have tried but seems to always run from $HOME
this particular command (terraform workspace show) has no options and only displays relevant output from that specific directory it runs from.